# ExpandoObject doesn't contain "ContainsKey"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.5

I'm writing an MVC application and am encapsulating the grabbing and passing of a series of settings to my views via an Action Filter. I can demonstrate this works fine in the debugger. I can directly hit the properties. However, as the settings are database-backed, I want to be able to test if a setting exists before I go off and expect the related properties to be attached to the object. I get the following:

> 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'ContainsKey'

Looking at the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt481543(v=vs.110).aspx), it most certainly does or at least should. My use-case also seems to fit [its intended usage](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/10/01/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject.aspx) as well. So, as far as I can tell, I'm not doing anything "weird" with this approach. Some screenshots of what I see in the debugger:

[image: What the debugger reports as the type]

[image: Hitting a target property in the settings object directly]

[image: Trying to test if the property exists in a programmatic way without risking exceptions]

Even though the QuickWatch window sees the settings of an object, I went back to check and most certainly do declare it as an `ExpandoObject` myself. Here is the code I use to generate and fill this object.

```
dynamic bag = filterContext.Controller.ViewBag;

bag.Settings = new ExpandoObject();
IDictionary<string, object> settingsDictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>) bag.Settings;

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, string>> pair in settings)
{
    settingsDictionary[pair.Key] = new ExpandoObject();
    IDictionary<string, object> innerDictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>) settingsDictionary[pair.Key];

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> innerValue in pair.Value)
    {
        innerDictionary[innerValue.Key] = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(innerValue.Value);
    }
}
```

All that code runs fine without an exception being thrown. Any ideas as to what's going on here?

Comment: Right, the `ExpandoObject` does not have that method, the `IDictionary<,>` interface does. Just because it implements that interface, doesn't mean that it has to expose the members it implements.

Comment: @JeffMercado That boggles my mind. How do you test to see if something is there without making throwing exceptions a normal result of execution? My .Net experience to date says you should not do that, period.

Comment: @Bigsby You shouldn't be using `dynamic` in the first place if you don't *know* that the member is there.  It's a fundamental premise of the feature.  If you don't actually know if the object has that member, you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: @Servy That would inherently limit its usefulness in acting as a "safe" mediator in COM interop scenarios. You don't always know what's there.

Comment: @Bigsby Then you shouldn't be using `dynamic`.  It exists to make it easier to write code when you *do* know exactly what's there.  If you don't, then you need to be doing what you'd do if you didn't have `dynamic`.

Comment: @Servy I disagree with your prescribed use case. Per Microsoft's own article on it: Therefore, you do not have to be concerned about whether the object gets its value from a COM API, from a dynamic language such as IronPython, from the HTML Document Object Model (DOM), from reflection, or from somewhere else in the program. It is absolutely useful for when you can't be sure as to its members. Its explicit usage in COM scenarios makes it ideal for old libraries that you may simply not have documentation for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ExpandoObject` provides an implementation for `ContainsKey` *as an explicit interface implementation of `IDictionary`.  That means that you can only access the method when the variable is of the type of the interface.

So to call `ContainsKey` you will need to access the `ExpandoObject` instance through a variable of type `IDictionary`, as you showed in your second example.

Comment: Whether I like it or not, this is indeed the answer.